# Type annotations for class parameters and return values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume I have the following:

```
from __future__ import annotations

class A(object):

    @classmethod
    def some_class_method(cls: ?, parameter: str) -> ?:
        return A
```

What should `?` become if I want to make it clear that `some_class_method` is returning **the class `A`** and **not** an instance of class `A`.

EDIT: @chepner Brought up a good point in that `?` likely is meant to refer to `A` or **any subclass of `A`**.

Comment: Keep in mind that `some_class_method` really can take `A` or a *subclass* of `A` as an argument. Do you really want to return `A`, or the class that is passed as the argument?

Comment: @chepner Yeah I see what you mean. For completeness sake, is there a way to specify both? So let's say I want to specify just A for the parameter but A or any subclass as the return value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `A` because it is not yet defined. Instead, you need to use `'A'`. You will also need to use `Type` since `'A'` means an instance of `A`:

```
from typing import Type

class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def some_class_method(cls: Type['A'], parameter: str) -> Type['A']:
        return A
```

Comment: The OP is using `annotations`, which prevents all annotations from being evaluated.

Comment: Keep in mind that the type only specifies that the return value will be a subclass of `A`, not necessarily `A` itself, and also not necessarily the same class used to invoke the method.